# Kendo Autocomplete is not working in Mozila

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, kendo-ui

I am applying Kendo Autocomplete on a textbox which is fetching Citylist. On Chrome its working fine when i test on Mozila then list comes and go away. It is flicking. Below is code which i have used for Auto-complete. Please guide me

```
$("#City").kendoAutoComplete({
  dataTextField: "Town",
  filter: "contains",
  minLength: 1,
  dataSource: {
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "JSON",
    serverFiltering: true,
    serverPaging: true,
    pageSize: 20,
    transport: {
      read: "/UKPostCode/GetArea",
      parameterMap: function (data, action) {
        if (action === "read") {
          return { city: $("#City").val() };
        } else {
          return data;
        }
      }
    }
  },
  change: function (e) {

  },
  select: function (e) {
    var item = this.dataItem(e.item.index());
    $("#County").val(item.County);
    $("#Region").val(item.Region);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that trail version of Kendo is having issue in Mozila. But if we can have professional version of Kendo,  this problem will solve. I have just replaced kendo.web.min.js file.